# If we assume that principle of quantum superposition is wrong, would this invalidate Alain Aspect experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition, linear-systems

If we assume that principle of quantum superposition would be actually not true, would this invalidate conclusion from the Alain Aspect experiment that there is no local hidden variable?

Comment: If the principle of quantum superposition would be actually not true it would break all of QM

Comment: Sure, but Alain Aspect is not testing QM : he is testing possibility of hidden variable. But if he starts by assuming that quantum superposition is true, then if this hypothesis is wrong, we could reject his conclusion that there is no hidden variable, so that it is still possible.

Comment: I think the logic of this question is backwards. A state in a superposition of two possibilities for a given observable, is by definition a state in which only probabilistic statements about the outcome can be made. The whole point of hidden variables is to say that these probabilities only exist in quantum mechanics because we don't have access to the true underlying degrees of freedom that define the state. So I think testing for hidden variables is also testing the superposition principle, in some sense. In a hidden variable theory, you might not need superposition states at all.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, what you are essentially you are essentially asking if Bell's argument that no local hidden variable theory can explain, for example, the result of the Aspect experiment, depend on the fact the is can be correctly described by quantum mechanics? If it was found that QM was fundamentally flawed, therefore, it might then reopen the possibility of local-hidden variable theories? If so I would suggest rephrasing the question to focus on "quantum mechanical theories" rather than "the principle of superposition" which is a bit of a red herring.

Comment: I don't master myself my question. My hypothesis is that quantum mechanics is wrong : that is : there are hidden variables that give the illustion that there is quantum mechanism. So Bell inegaliry is tested with Alain Aspect experiment and tend to say that there is no hidden variable. But at the very beginning, already his experiment is assuming that there is a quantum superposition, so I have no reason to believe the first assumption.

Answer (score 1):

The principle of superposition is not unique to quantum mechanics. It lies at the foundation of (classical) interferometry. It is therefore not an assumption anymore, but a well-establish physical principle based on ample experimental evidence.

The only complication that quantum mechanics adds to this principle is that individual terms in the superposition can consist of multiple particle, each carrying a full compliment of the degrees of freedom of the field, as opposed to just one such set of degrees of freedom as found in classical theories.

So, it would be difficult to separate out the quantum aspect of this principle in Alain Aspect's experimental results.

Comment: This is extremely interesting. So with classical mechanic and electromagnetic, we already allow superposition of field. OK. This is a key point.